# How to draw a two dimensional graph in LaTeX?

Tags: pgfplots

I have a set of data containing x-values and y-values. Say x=1,3,5,7,9 and
y=26,28,30,28,26.

How to plot it in LaTeX? The graph will be a straight line increasing till x=5, and then will start decreasing on x=7,9.

Comment: see this: http://www.pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/linear-plot/

Comment: @nidhin Thank you so much. i want ed to label  both the axis as x-axis and y-axis. Also i dont want to appear the graph in square box, just to appear as xy-plane.

Comment: The label part is done. now i wanted to remove the square shape. just to looks like xy-plane

Comment: see other examples: http://www.pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/all/?page=1

Comment: @nidhin. Thanks it works, but now i am struggling with the color as it appear blue and i need black color for the graph of the function.

Comment: use `\addplot[black] coordinates ...` instead of `\addplot+[..] coordinates ...`

Comment: @nidhin Got it. Thank you so much